# Convolution with a 3x3 kernel doesn't work

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to apply a 3x3 filter kernel to an image. The code is interpreted without an error, but I no image is displayed? 
What can I do?

```
def main():

    imgpath = "g.jpg"
    img = cv2.imread(imgpath, 1)
    import numpy as np
    img = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


    k = np.array(np.ones((11, 11), np.float64))/121

    k = np.array(([2, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 2, 2]), np.float64)

    print(k)


    output = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, k)

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.title('Original Image')

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(output)
    plt.title('Filtered Image')

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please get some Python basics right. There is no compiler in Python. It's an interpreted language.

Comment: Code runs for me, once you add lines to import cv2 & matplotlib. So not sure why you didn't get a 'compile/interpreted' error

Comment: @cdplayer I already add lines to import cv2 and matplotlib and the other libraries but I don't know why it still not executed and the images are not shown

Comment: @cdplayer the code runs for me too , but why the output are tow white images with no content ?

Answer (score 2):

Except the missing module import part, basically, your codes are correct.

The output image is as empty as white, right?
The root cause is the filtered value larger than RGB range, 0~255.

When applying filter, you should keep the output data range be still fall in 0~255.
That is,

```
k = np.array(([2, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 2, 2]), np.float64)
k = k / 19
```

[image: Blurred image]

So, for a simple smooth filter, it will be

```
k = np.array(([1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]), np.float64)
k = k / 9
```

How about Sobel (in horizontal)?

```
k = np.array(([1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]), np.float64)
```

Yes, keep k as k.

[image: Sobel sample]

Back to the start, I suggest you paste also the import part you used. It will help others know your problem doesn't come from missing import:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Comment: thank you first for trying to help me but the output image should be bluer image ...

Comment: @user3803761 yes, the output of your original codes is the blurred image. What I pasted is to show the Sobel result.

Comment: Let me paste the result of yours (with fix) in the post.

Comment: I make import for all the packages which you tell me about but it still the same problem (nothing interpret)

Comment: @user10040689  what should I do pleas ?

Comment: Actually, Sobel outputs negative values, which you are not showing in your display, they end up all black. Ideally you’d stretch the filter result so that zero ends up as a medium gray in the display.

Comment: @user3803761: you have your answer here. Please read the answer carefully. Especially the bit about the range of gray values in the output and how to fix that by scaling your filter.